# How to use an express server for production alongside webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

I'm currently building an app with React, which talks to an API on a separate backend. In my `server.js` I have express listening on one port for `WebpackDevServer`, and another port for serving a simple `index.html`. Here is what things look like:

```
new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  })
  .listen(3001, '0.0.0.0', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('Running at http://0.0.0.0:3001');
  });

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log('Running at http://0.0.0.4000')
})
```

- How can I conditionally choose which server to run depending on my env? I don't want both ports to have an instance of my front-end running.
- What would be a good way to modify the `scripts` section in `package.json` to accommodate the changes?

Comment: what is the purpose of listening for a web pack instance ?
1. Webpack dev server is only for development purposes, so you shouldn't tie in your api to listen to a WebpackDevServer given you will probably deploy that API at some point.
2. React comes prebuilt with webpack so i would defer to React's methods of handling your index.html since you simply want to re serve it.

Comment: Well I'm not 'tying' my API to anything, it's a Rails backend on another port, independent of express. Also, React technically does not come prebuilt with webpack.

Comment: Apologies, React comes "configured" with web pack. Just wanted to understand why you are not just using the default config with react. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your code into two separate files. And start them depending on your environment.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start-dev": "node src/webpack.js",
    "start-prod": "node src/server.js"
  }
```

Comment: The above method works, but here is a helpful link for anyone wanting to do things with a single configuration file: [link](http://nikolay.rocks/2016-01-13-connect-webpack-to-backend)